# How can I connect my Windows XP PC to an LG WiFi TV?

Tags: windows-xp, hdtv

I recently bought an LG Infinia 6500 PC that has a wireless network adapter with it that plugs into one of its USB ports. It also has an Ethernet jack, but currently I am streaming through the Apps on the TV, which include Netflix, etc etc.

How can I stream stuff to my TV from my computer? The reason for this is my computer has a hard drive, so I want to be able to use a service like Vudu, save the movie for later to watch, and then stream it from my PC to the TV.

Will this be possible with this combination of devices?
I was also thinking of investigating making my PC into a [Boxee device](http://www.boxee.tv/make) but I'm just not sure how to hook the PC and TV together.

I'd also appreciate any recommendations on other services that let you stream to HDD, then watch later. My Internet is too slow to stream a HD signal in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the media sharing software on your local PC. It will then broadcast its availability over your network (both wired and wifi). Your TV should then detect it and display it its list of available devices.

This is what we do with our LG TV. We actually have a NAS that has a TwonkyMedia server built into it, but the contept is the same.

As for Boxee, it requires your computer to be physically connected to your TV, via HDMI or DVI. This is not what you're describing in your question - you're describing streaming directly from your PC to your TV.